# Не срабатывает callback при повторном нажатии на элемент

Tags: jquery, ul

Кастомизирую **select**. Делаю это через выпадающий список, в общем. При нажатии на элемент с классом **choose** к нему добавляется класс **active** и при повторном нажатии удаляется. Но эта процедура срабатывает один раз, и при дальнейших нажатиях класс добавляется и удаляется снова, как и должен, но **callback** не срабатывает, т.е. список снова не выпадает.

```js
$('.choose').on('click', function() {
  $('.list').show();

  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('.active').on('click', function() {
      $('.list').hide();
    });

  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.white-triangle-down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #fff;
}
.select {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.select p {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}
ul.list {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <p class="choose">Выберете статус</p>
  <div class="white-triangle-down"></div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <p>Пункт1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Пункт2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Пункт3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем все так усложнять?

```
$('.choose').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.list').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.list').show();
  }
});
```